# Overflow and z-index issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

as you see on image [image]

my main div has overflow:hidden;

but my select box which is position absolute is not as expect how can I fix it ?

my main div class

```
 border-top: 2px solid #00b9ff;
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

and my selectbox div classes

```
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 2;
    color: #FFF;
```

Comment: I don't get it .. What are you expecting ? Which `div` is the "`main div`" you're talking about ? Show us your HTML code, we can't do anything without it.

Comment: Try to add `position:relative;` to your main div class. What does it do ?

Comment: demo link: http://212.15.4.166:88/works/ani/tur_anasayfa.html

Comment: if u click selectbox you'r gonna understand my english is not enought to explain that

Comment: Remove the `overflow:hidden;` from `.carousel-inner` and add a `height` value. (here `height:338px` seems to fit)

Comment: @PoulsQ thanks but didn't work it nothing happend  :/

Comment: @fortherest Sorry I made a mistake : remove the `overflow:hidden;` from `#tur-detay-carousel` and add a `height` value to `.carousel-inner`.

Comment: Remove `overflow:hidden;` form your id `#tur-detay-carousel` and add `z-index:20` to your class `.tur-detay-search`

Comment: @fortherest does it solves your problem ?

Comment: it's great @PoulsQ thanks it work's very well

Comment: @fortherest I'll propose an answer, don't forget to validate me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your test page : http://212.15.4.166:88/works/ani/tur_anasayfa.html

Remove the `overflow:hidden;`from `#tur-detay-carousel` and add a `height` value to `.carousel-inner`. (here `height:338px` seems to fit)